# Regular expression matching in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column in my table with the following values:

```
'2.190.44.6'
'2.185.36.5'
'2.180.85.8'
'2.180.53.5'
'2.170.49.5'
'2.160.55.8'
'2.145.37.5'
```

I want to fetch only latest values and be generic to address values which will be added in future.

Currently the following would not work:

```
select device from table
where device NOT LIKE '2.1[0-7]%.[0-7]%'
```

Results should be only the following values:

```
'2.190.44.6'
'2.185.36.5'
'2.180.85.8'
'2.180.53.5'
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get away with just using `substring` here:

```
SELECT device
FROM yourTable
WHERE substring(device for 4) = '2.18' OR
      substring(device for 4) = '2.19'
```

See [TechOnTheNet](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/substring.php) for a good resource on how to use Postgres' `substring` function.

**Update:**

If you plan on having a `2.0` release in the future, and you just want to match the first minor version pattern, then you can modify the query as follows:

```
SELECT device
FROM yourTable
WHERE substring(device from 3 for 2) = '18' OR
      substring(device from 3 for 2) = '19'
```